# How to join group using SignalR Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr

I'm looking to figure out how to correctly join groups as SignalR-ObjectiveC is not very well documented. I have set up my application to communicate via SignalR in the following way:

```
-(void)ConnectSignalR{

    // Connect to the service
    SRHubConnection *hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"xxx"];

    // Register for connection lifecycle events
    [hubConnection setStarted:^{
        NSLog(@"Connection Started");
    }];
    [hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *message) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Recieved Data: %@",message);
    }];
    [hubConnection setConnectionSlow:^{
        NSLog(@"Connection Slow");
    }];
    [hubConnection setReconnecting:^{
        NSLog(@"Connection Reconnecting");
    }];
    [hubConnection setReconnected:^{
        NSLog(@"Connection Reconnected");
    }];
    [hubConnection setClosed:^{
        NSLog(@"Connection Closed");
    }];
    [hubConnection setError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Error %@",error);
    }];
    // Start the connection
    [hubConnection start];
}

- (void)addMessage:(NSString *)message {
    // Print the message when it comes in
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

I then call these methods by doing the following in my main view controller:

```
-(void)SignalR{

    WebServices *services = [[WebServices alloc] init];

    [services ConnectSignalR];

    [services callGetSRGroupNames:^(NSMutableArray *resultsArray) {
        NSLog(@"SR GROUP NAMES: %@", resultsArray);

        SRHubConnection *hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"xxx"];

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < [resultsArray count]; i++) {
            [hubConnection setGroupsToken:resultsArray[i]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Is this correct? I receive the following back but am not sure its correct:

```
WS: websocket did receive: {"C":"s-0,94445","S":1,"M":[]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining to a group is a server side thing. You need to create a hub method (server side) that adds a connection to a group and then invoke this hub method from the client. Take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) for more details.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to invoke a hub method from the client?

Comment: I found it in samples - e.g. https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/blob/c412cc38618b27c83fe170eaa9da95aa0c7eb42a/Example/Networking/DrawingPadConnection.m#L48

Comment: For those wondering, the magic incantation looks like this: [_hub invoke:@"join" withArgs:@[] completionHandler:nil];